# pax change directory similar to tar

Tags: backup, archiving

`tar` has  -C, --directory DIR: change to directory DIR. Does pax have something similar? This can be useful for backing up directory structures/hierarchies in a relative fashion, such as `./sysconfig`, instead of `/etc/sysconfig`, or restoring from inside a directory other than $TARGET_DIR.

I normally use pax in ustar (default) format, or sometimes cpio.

Comment: It might be a newer parameter, but cpio now has a -D parameter.
Such as: cpio -D somefolder -i < archive.cpio path/file1
This will extract file1 to ./somefolder/path/file1

Answer (score 0):

```
(cd /etc && pax args) > outputfile

(cd /etc && tar xvz) < inputfile
```

Equivalent to `tar -C`.